# Retrieving objects with condition on their duration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a model "Competition" with attributes start_at and end_at, both of type datetime. I would like to retrieve only competitions with a duration shorter that a given amount, for example 3 days. I would expect to do this easily:

```
Competition.where('end_at - start_at < ?', X)
```

The problem: what do I use for X?

In my database I have one competition object with a duration of slightly less than one day (start_at = 2011-04-27 00:00:00, end_at = 2011-04-27 23:59:59) and one slightly less than 3 days (start_at = 2013-02-05 00:00:00, end_at 2013-02-07 23:59:59), all others are much longer.

To retrieve the shorter of the two, I expected to use X = 60*60*24 (number of seconds in 24 hours). Doesn't work. SO I tried to multiply by an increasing factor and found that multiplying X by 2.7 will not retrieve it, but 2.8 will ! So OK, I need to use this strange factor 2.8...
But this does not work for retrieving objects shorter than 3 days. Here I need to multiply by 8.7. Does anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The functions available depend on the database you're using. For example, with SQLite, you can use:

```
Competition.where('julianday(end_at) - julianday(start_at) < ?', 3)
```

Comment: I use MySQL. Don't know/think it has julianday

Comment: But you put me on the right track! replacing julianday by date in your expression works. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Competition.where('DATEDIFF(end_at, start_at) < ?', x)
```

For more accurate

```
Competition.where('TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_at, end_at) < ?', x*86400)  #where 86400 is the seconds in a day and x is no. of days
```